# Retrieving values from json file using jq

Tags: json, jq

How can I print the value after "games", "toys", "books"?
Here's the output of jq '.' on the file:

> ```
>  {
>     "reports": [
>         {
>           "games": 3,
>           "toys": 0,
>           "books": 3,
>           "to": "2017-07-22T00:00:00.000+0000",
>           "from": "2017-07-21T00:00:00.000+0000",
>           "eventType": "bookedIn",
>           "rowName": "CWQ"
>         },
>         {
>           "games": 0,
>           "toys": 0,
>           "books": 0,
>           "to": "2017-07-22T00:00:00.000+0000",
>           "from": "2017-07-21T00:00:00.000+0000",
>           "eventType": "bookedOut",
>           "rowName": "AED"
>         }
>     ]
>  }
> ```

I tried with

> { echo "["; cat file; echo "]"; } |
>       jq -r '
>            .[] | 
>           (
>               "\n" + .rowName + ":",
>               "games -> " + (.games | tostring),
>              "toys -> "  + (.toys  | tostring),
>                "books -> " + (.books | tostring)
>            ) 
>        '

It seems I'm doing something wrong.

**UPDATE**
Just for my knowledge assuming that books have another 2 items: provider and name :-?

```
jq -r '.reports |
.[] |
("\n" + .rowName + ":",
 "Games: " + (.games | tostring),
 "Toys: " + (.toys | tostring),
 .books | .[] |
 ("\n" + .name + ": ",
 "provider: " + (.provider | tostring) ) ) 
' response.json
```

Ill get jq: error (at response.json:1): Cannot iterate over null (null)

Comment: That's what happens when you change the requirements after the product is delivered.

Comment: you are missing the closing `]`

Comment: There are multiple  { } like those too I did put them all and I forgot to close it after the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the JSON command line parser `jq`:

```
$ jq -r '.reports[] |          
         "\(.rowName) :",     
         "books -> \(.books)",
         "toys -> \(.toys)",  
         "games -> \(.games)\n"' input.json

CWQ:
books -> 3
toys -> 0
games -> 3

AED:
books -> 0
toys -> 0
games -> 0
```

Note: This uses `jq`'s string interpolation and iterates over all entries in the `reports` array, picking out the relevant information.

---

Update: Handling `.books` being an array of objects:

Given

```
{
  "reports": [
    {
      "games": 3,
      "toys": 0,
      "books": [
        {
          "provider": "The provider",
          "name": "The name"
        }
      ],
      "to": "2017-07-22T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "from": "2017-07-21T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "eventType": "bookedIn",
      "rowName": "CWQ"
    },
    {
      "games": 0,
      "toys": 0,
      "books": [
        {
          "provider": "The 1st provider",
          "name": "The 1st name"
        },
        {
          "provider": "The 2nd provider",
          "name": "The 2nd name"
        }
      ],
      "to": "2017-07-22T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "from": "2017-07-21T00:00:00.000+0000",
      "eventType": "bookedOut",
      "rowName": "AED"
    }
  ]
}
```

We can simply do

```
$ jq -r '.reports[] |
         "\(.rowName):",
         ( .books[] | "book name -> \(.name)",
                      "book provider -> \(.provider)" ),
         "toys -> \(.toys)",
         "games -> \(.games)\n"'

CWQ:
book name -> The name
book provider -> The provider
toys -> 0
games -> 3

AED:
book name -> The 1st name
book provider -> The 1st provider
book name -> The 2nd name
book provider -> The 2nd provider
toys -> 0
games -> 0
```

Comment: I cannot use jq command unfortunately :(

Comment: @Kimmyshor Why?

Comment: I don't have the packages and I'm not able to install those :(

Comment: @Kimmyshor I'm happy to see that you managed to install `jq`.

Comment: Yes, well I realized that you can't make omelet without breaking few eggs...

Comment: @Kimmyshor And you can't parse structured data without a proper parser.

Comment: hei @kusalananda , I got the point but on books has another pray of [ ] before {}, that's where I have difficulties :(

Comment: @Kimmyshor Updated my answer.

Comment: I'm getting: jq: error: Cannot iterate over null, at books :(

Comment: @Kimmyshor Then you either mistyped something, or I don't know what your updated JSON data looks like (you never put it in the question).

Comment: sorry I was looking at first query :D thanks the second one works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v RS='[{},]' '/^"(games|toys|books)"/{ sub("^.*:",""); print; }' file
0
0
0
50
30
20
10
30
20
```

or for just one word:

```
awk -v pattern=games -v RS='[{},]' '$0 ~ "^\"" pattern "\"" { sub("^.*:",""); print; }' file
0
50
10
```

Comment: this also works: cat result.txt | tr '":{}[]' ',' | awk -F "," '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i == "books") print $(i+2)}' , but i need to add text between them

Answer (score 0):

Let's parse that JSON with a JSON parser, [jq](/questions/tagged/jq).

```
jq -r '
    .reports |
    .[] |
    (
        "\n" + .rowName + ":",
        "games -> " + (.games | tostring),
        "toys -> "  + (.toys  | tostring),
        "books -> " + (.books | tostring)
    )
' file
```

```
CWQ:
games -> 3
toys -> 0
books -> 3

AED:
games -> 0
toys -> 0
books -> 0
```